# How to inflate a layout from a class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

So I am trying to inflate a layout from a class but so far no luck at all ... The layout is a loading spinner I want the spinner to be inflated when the class is called because there is an Asynch task withing the class. I want the inflated layout to be removed when the Asynch task finishes. But so far I have nothing.

Here is my XML for the spinner

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/LoadingSpinner"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ProgressBar>
```

And my class

```
 public class ClusterManager extends ClusterManager {

 public ClusterManager(LayoutInflator inflator) {
 super();        
  this.inflater = inflater;
}

 private void reload() {

 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
 {
     @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        //Start spinner here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        //Stop/Remove the spinner
    }
  }.execute();

  }
```

I have tried to inflate it like this.

```
 View loadingView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.loading_spinner,null);
```

But no result the layout is not inflated nothing is shown on the screen. What am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to inflate it or there is something that I am missing?

Comment: Inflating a layout creates a GUI object (e.g. a `View`). But you will have to take care of telling it when or where to show itself, for example by adding it to a (visible) `Activity`.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Hi maybe you are looking for a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: No I want the user to see just a spinning circle not a  whole dialog

Comment: You have to add the inflated view to the view hierarchy somewhere. This means you need to reference a ViewGroup in your layout and call `addView` to add it (and `removeView` to remove it). It might be easier to have the spinner in the layout all the time and just use `setVisibility` to show or hide it as necessary.

Comment: @Karakuri  I was thinking the exact same thing but I have a few setbacks how do I reference a ViewGroup? And how can I define the spinner because in the class I cant use findviewbyId?

Comment: You'll have to do something like pass a FragmentManager to your `reload()` method so you can show a DialogFragment with the spinner. There may be other ways to do it. Alternatively, implement some communication mechanism between your UI code and this class and have the UI code be responsible for the spinner.